# I can login to sysadm as sysdba but not without sysdba parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am running Oracle 12c on Linux, and I am able to login to sysadm ONLY with the sysdba parameter but when I remove the SYSDBA parameter it fails

```
sqlplus sysadm/MYPASSWORD

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 9 12:17:47 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


sqlplus sysadm/MYPASSWORD as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed May 9 12:17:30 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm guessing your password is incorrect/expired. When you connect using `as sysdba` locally, it uses **OS authentication**, not password authentication.

Comment: SYSADM was migrated using impdp ... in Oracle 11 c I am able to connect via sysplus sysadm/PASSWORD but within 12c it fails and I am only able to connect via sysplus sysadmin/PASSWORD as sysdba

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct, including its case?

Comment: Hello Alex,  yes, I just logged in via sqlplus sysadm/ (didn't put password) then put it in when it prompted me for it and it worked

Comment: Does the password have special characters that are being interpreted by the shell, maybe, like a $ sign?

Comment: no special characters all lowercase letters and 2 numbers

Comment: Is this something they did away with in 12C?